# Complex htaccess URL and variable rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url, variables, dynamic, url-rewriting

I run a mmo game fan site http://www.ddmsrealm.com. In this site I have run a databse with quest and item information for years. It was originally built with MSSQL/ASP and I have recently converted it to MYSQL/PHP. In this conversion I optimized the database. In doing so I changed a bit of the structure and variables. Now, the new pages are up and running but I am having a terrible time trying to write rules in my htaccess file to accommodate the hundreds of quests and thousands of items to reroute to the new database pages with the new database variables.  Any and all help would be appreciated as I struggle to learn apache/htaccess.

I have two “details” pages that need to be rerouted along with having the variable names changed. The actual ID's are still the same so it should work.

Original Quest Page was an asp page:

~http://www.ddmsrealm.com/ddo/quests/QDetail.aspx

Permanent reroute to new Quest Details Page(WordPress Template Page):

~http://www.ddmsrealm.com/index.php/dungeons-and-dragons-quest-and-magic-item-database/dungeons-and-dragons-online-quest-info

Now the parameters need to be rewritten like this:

Old: QuestID to New: ddoQuestID

Old: SeriesID to New: ddoSeriesID

So the idea is that this:

~http://www.ddmsrealm.com/ddo/quests/QDetail.aspx?QuestID=210&SeriesID=30

Is permanently redirected as this:

~http://www.ddmsrealm.com/index.php/dungeons-and-dragons-quest-and-magic-item-database/dungeons-and-dragons-online-quest-info?ddoQuestID=210&ddoSeriesID=30

If I can get the formula and steps for this I am sure I can apply it to the other pages. Being new to htaccess rewriting I am struggling to understand what exactly needs to happen and in what order. As you can imagine, this has jacked up my SEO bad having about 5000+ pages now going to a 404. Plus hundreds of websites have linked that old URL and now those links are trashed until I can resolve this.

Thank you so much in advance for the help figuring this out!

Comment: Do you need to have separate rewrite condition and rules together. So instead of appending the existing one I should make another one for another URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI rewrite itself is pretty straight forward using a `RewriteRule` but changing the query string you'll need to use a `RewriteCond` and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable and backreference the matches using the **%** symbol. See the docs for more info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Match the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} QuestID=([0-9]+)&SeriesID=([0-9]+)
# Rewrite the URI and append the new query string
RewriteRule ^ddo/quests/QDetail.aspx$ /index.php/dungeons-and-dragons-quest-and-magic-item-database/dungeons-and-dragons-online-quest-info?ddoQuestID=%1&ddoSeriesID=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: OK thanks! I think I see what you are doing. So the first step is to grab the variables. Then with those you are just dropping them into the rewrite rule.  So then can I grab other variables by just adding &RareItemID=([0-9]+)? This would then be %3 to which I can insert into a new Rewrite rule just below the first one? Going from one "house of programing" to the other is melting my brain. Thanks!

Comment: @user1518699 *"So then can I grab other variables by just adding &RareItemID=([0-9]+)? This would then be %3 to which I can insert into a new Rewrite rule just below the first one?"* Yeah, as long as it's after the other 2 you can backrefernce is using **%3**.